# Disagreeing with a decision to close a question

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions

In my opinion a reasonable question was asked.  "how can i add a button on ms access report to export it to excel / pdf   any help appreciated."   Not the most elegant question but certanily enough for me to give several links to VBA code with answers.  Which I did in the comments.  Now there are non VBA means of getting Excel and PDF reports but I've used VBA lots for this before which has a number of advantages.

However, Jeff Atwood closed [How can I add a button to an Access report to export it to Excel / PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740990/how-can-i-add-a-button-on-ms-access-report-to-export-it-to-excel-pdf) stating "closed as not programming related"

Which of course I disagree with.
So now what?
How do I send Jeff an email?

Comment: I cleaned it up and voted to reopen.

Comment: Should have a "jeff-said-so" tag... :-) my new favorite tag: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jeff-said-so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've got less than 3000 rep on Stack Overflow your option are:

a) mention it here in the hope that 5 3000+ rep SO users will see the question and vote to reopen - which you have done!

b) flag it as requiring moderator attention explaining why in the comment.

c) earn more SO rep so you can vote to reopen yourself.

Comment: Yeah, well, I specialize in MS Access and now starting to answer VB 6 questions so it'll take while for my SO rep to increase sufficiently.  <smile>

Answer (score 0):

It will usually get reopened if enough high-rep users thing it's actually a viable question. Commenting on the post as you did is usually a good way to get their attention.

Saying that: in this case, Jeff closed it, so you probably won't get many users disagreeing with him - though of course, it's a community run site, so anyone with 3000+ rep can vote to reopen. (That's just 800 more for you it seems.)

Comment: Yeah -- nobody around here ever disagrees with @Jeff.  ;-)

Comment: tvanfossen.  <chuckle>

Holdorin, so how is commenting to a closed question sufficient to get other folks attention?   It would appear I don't understand some of the finer points of SO.  Which doesn't surprise me.

Comment: @Tony Toews: Well what else could you do? Complain to Jeff? Er, wait... he just closed it. Just kidding. :) Usually users who come across it will reopen it if they think it worthy - a comment *might* help them make up their mind.

Comment: But how will folks with a high enough SO standing come across that message?   I only view messages with certain tags.   Other than that I don't poke about.   And there aren't a lot of folks with high enough points that answer Access questions.   Yet.  A few of us are working on that.

Comment: @Tony: If it really bothers you, just flag it for moderator attention, no?

Comment: Noldorin   Oh, so enough modeators would then see it and vote on it?  Ok, that makes sense.     As far as bothering me goes I tend to try and put myself in the shoes of these not so clued in folks as we are.  So I try to be helpful and point them in the right direction.   Knowing full well that they might be so clueless about things they will never, ever find their previous posting again.  <wry smile>

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything. It was only closed, if 5 people feel that its a valid question, they can vote to reopen.

At this point, one person has already done so.

Comment: 3 now, including my vote.

Comment: Enough voted to reopen the question that I've moved my comment to a reply.