# Retribution and disagreeing with the intransigence of others

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, reopen-closed, vote-to-reopen

When I read a question that I think is perfectly reasonable, but which sufficient others have voted to close, obviously [I can (and do) disagree](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29994/disagreeing-with-a-decision-to-close-a-question) and vote to reopen, but what's the best practice on vengeance?

My first reaction is to see the list of those responsible and to head off like a one user posse and to go over some of their contributions with a strict eye and to look for any reason to vote them down or edit them to improve. But this doesn't seem within the spirit of the trilogy.

I should be grown up and just move on, after all it probably wasn't my question, I might not even have answered it and there are hundreds of others to get to work on, but if I feel positive enough to vote up a question that someone else has voted to close, it's a human reaction to want to visit some furious anger on those responsible for closing it.

What methods to y'all employ to, just, get over it?

**Edit:**

My basis for this is that if I can't agree with someone on something, i.e. that they are wrong, then what else are they wrong about and isn't it my duty to help the community by highlighting this? Obviously just moving on is relatively easily said (and done).

Comment: Just vote to reopen and move on. You should be treating each post on it's own merits.

Comment: Yeah, take that! I'm going to edit *all your posts* and make them *better* so you'll get *more upvotes*! That'll teach you to mess with me!

Answer (score 21):

The best thing to do is close your browser and get some work done.  If you get so offended by a close vote on *somebody else's question* that you think you need retribution, then you've got too much personally invested and need to take a step back.

The second-best thing to do is go gain some reputation by answering other questions.  "The best revenge is living well."

Answer (score 15):

Some suggestions:

2. Go for a walk.
3. Watch a movie.
4. Listen to some music.
5. Play a violent video game.
6. Seriously just get over it. Holy crap it's not at all normal for you to want to punish people for having opinions that differ from yours. What are you, eight years old?
7. Go for a swim.
8. Maybe go to that restaurant you like.
9. Petty vandalism (the pettier the bettier).
10. Play a non-violent video game (like Audiosurf (see suggestion 3)).
11. Make fun of Jeff Atwood (this is my personal favorite).
12. Read a good book.
13. Write a good book.
14. Find a new hobby (for example, model laser construction).

Comment: I prefer thatched roof demolition myself.

Comment: Model laser construction encourages retribution with lasers.

Comment: They're only models.

Comment: @Welbog: I am dissapointed that your profile doesn't say "Hey man do you back up your data? F yeah you do!".

Comment: @Bon J: If you don't get the obvious joke in my profile then I'm just going to have to pilfer through your old posts to edit, close and downvote them.

Comment: @Welbog your in luck, I just happened to make a backup for you. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31781/which-users-about-me-section-has-impressed-you-most/32328#32328

Answer (score 5):

You said it already. **Grow up and move along**

In the real world not everyone is going to agree with everyone else, so do you go around and deflate everyone's car tires because of it? Hopefully not.

So why should it be any different online?

Chances are revenge votes and tactics is going to end up getting **you** time in the penalty box, leaving others blissfully unaware of your existence.

Answer (score 4):

Counseling.

Answer (score 4):

There's a certain irony to this, given my current Meta name (which is itself a joke), but if you feel the need for vengeance, you have the wrong mindset.

Under no circumstance should you go out looking for vengeance on someone. The bottom line is that reasonable people can disagree. Disagreements are not always spiteful in nature. There are people who will be wrong, and people who will be right, and the truth is that in many cases there merest small circumstances will be the differentiating factor.

On the Trilogy, all posts should be evaluated based on the content of the post, and not the individual writing it. Period.

Answer (score 2):

You're saying that if you disagree with someone that makes them wrong. And if they are wrong about one thing, they are probably wrong about more things - which you must correct or punish.

There is a word for this: fascism.

Comment: Actually, I think it is egoism, not fascism..

Answer (score -1):

> [**Unsliced**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2902/unsliced) said:
>
> "*If I can't agree with someone on something, then what else are they wrong about and isn't it my duty to help the community by highlighting this? Obviously just moving on is relatively easily said (and done).*"

Most of the times the easy way is the right way. Think about it.